# FB JS API - How to get ONLY new comments

Tags: facebook, api

Using the FB JS API (graph or fql), how can I get new comments since my last request (a supplied datetime).

I can get posts since, but if I sync the data up then someone adds a comment I dont seem to have a way of getting at just that NEW comment; other than submitting a request for all comments for all post ids I have then parsing them!

Any pointers welcomed!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Getting posts `since` just means give them the last time you checked and they'll provide posts that have occurred since then (hence the parameter being called "since"). I don't understand what you're getting confused about.

Comment: If you read my question again, you will see that I am not asking about posts since, I am asking about comments since.  Using FQL, the comments table doesnt have an indexable column since/time etc so I cant just get them that way.  I can get statuses/posts since, but that doesnt help there could be no new posts/statuses, but with new comments.

Comment: Using the graph explorer there is no 'me/comments' endpoint.  I know there is a connection, but cant seem to get the graph explorer to combine the posts and comments nodes, where the since applies to the comment time, rather than the post.

Comment: ** I would still like an answer to this, but have a workaround for now **

Comment: I use JS to build the html for my page/posts and keep track of the fb object ids of the posts on the page.  I then use fb fql batch queries.  the first of which gets the object ids of the statuses currently on page, then the second gets the comments since the last update, using the indexable statusid from the first query.  It doesnt seem like an efficient way of doing it, but until someone can help me out its what I will have to stick with.

Comment: PS @TommyCrush, are you really a facebook intern?

Comment: PPS, just found updated time, rather than created time on the posts endpoint.  will explore this.

Comment: Yes, I know you're referring to comments. Sorry, thought the parameter was `since`. That doesn't make sense now that I think about it. It's clearly `time`. And yes, I am interning at FB this summer in Menlo Park.

Comment: Hey, that sounds really cool.  How did you get in to that?

Comment: Build something cool and complex. Apply. And you'll get an interview.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the `comment` table in FQL lists a `time` parameter. You're correct, it is not indexable, but it can still be used in a query.

This type of query would satisfy what you're looking for:

`SELECT text FROM comment WHERE post_id="**POST_ID**" AND time > **UNIX_TIMESTAMP_OF_YOUR_LAST_CHECK**`

Comment: Hi, this is basically how I said I was doing it already?  I was hoping for something that wouldnt mean maintaining an active list of posts on screen, or querying for relevant posts, before then checking the comments.

Comment: I thought the following would give me what I want (according to the documentation... but it seems to be ignoring the since clause) [link](https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,posts.fields(created_time,message,comments),posts.updated_time?since=2013-03-02T01:01:01 0000)

Comment: More simply, this doesnt appear to work (even though it appears to be valid) - me/posts?fields=updated_time?since=2013-03-01T21:11:13 0000.  It shows all posts regardless.

Comment: `since` is a UNIX Timestamp, not a date object. You need to convert that datetime object to a unix timestamp before you use it in the query. Also, that URL is malformed. You need me/posts?fields=updated_time&since=   notice the & instead of the ?